Encoding a URL with : and / in their queries
Im trying to write a spring app for reporting to use XCP/Xen servers rest api and hitting a bit of an issue with the URI's and how they pass through their search/tags
to filter you need to pass through uri of
filter=tags:/^Backups$/i
which is encoded from : onwards resulting in a uri string of
tags%3A%2F%5EBackups%24%2Fi
Currently using the RestClient (not RestTemplate) and hitting in an issue where : and / dont get encoded (which makes sense)
I have tried manually adding this in in the uriBuilder and also encoding it before it gets added into the query params, both resulting in % being encoded and breaking the query
URL
Passing a string into RestClients .uri does encode but agin ignores : and / and passing a pre-encoded string with URLEncode (which itself does give an expected result), causes the same above issue with % gets encoded by RestClient.
I did also try using URI.Create which then just throws invalid exception
Is there a way around this and something i am missing (most likley)
For the original code I have
public List<VMLink> getVMsByTags(String[] tag){

    return restClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path(baseURI + "vms")
                    .queryParam("fields", "name_label,power_state")
                    .queryParam("filter=tags:" + 
StringConverters.tagArrayToTagRegex(tag))
                    .build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .retrieve()
            .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
}


VMlink being a simple record and tagArrayToRegex basically adds /^ and /$i either side
I am not 100% sure why XO requires the slash but it does even in search as shown below:
Search Example
I have also tested this via postman with links to those images as well.
Working with everything encoded including : and /
Not Working following RFC3986
Not working, all raw and no encoding
Additionally the docs on the API are here.
I may create a post as per their link at the bottom or send a ticket through.

According to the URI specification RFC 3986, neither : or / need to be encoded in the query part of a URI.  So it should not be a problem that they are encoded in one context and not in another.  Apart from that, I am not sure that I understand your problem description.  Please provide the relevant fragments of your code to show how you are encoding the URLs.

Yeah read through the RFC and believe this is more Xen Orchestra not following the RFC. Will edit original post with some more info

"I may create a post as per their link at the bottom or send a ticket through." - You should do that.  Even if only to get their opinion on whether the : and / characters should be encoded ... and why.
